# C# runs Powershell with Get-MpThreatDetection

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

If you run the command "Get-MpThreatDetection" in the powershell console you get (if any threats was found in the past) 17 Attributes shown in the console. But now I try the same command on a c# app, I get only the DetectionID and the ThreatID. If I try the same thing with the "help" command, I get the exact same Output on both ways.
But why?

C# Code:

```
 using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-MpThreatDetection");
            Collection<PSObject> result = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            foreach (PSObject r in result)
            {
                PSResult.Add(r.BaseObject.ToString());
            }
        }
```

(If you want to make a test threat to get something back with this command, save a Textfile with the Code in [this link](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html).)

Output from Powershell:
[Powershell Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDhxO.png)

Output from the Code:

> MSFT_MpThreatDetection (DetectionID = "{E186D279-4BA0-4FA5-8CD2-84F2D053CA6D}", ThreatID = 2147519003)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Answere even without powershell.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Defender", 
                "SELECT * FROM MSFT_MpThreatDetection"); 

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("MSFT_MpThreatDetection instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("ActionSuccess: {0}", queryObj["ActionSuccess"]);
                Console.WriteLine("AdditionalActionsBitMask: {0}", queryObj["AdditionalActionsBitMask"]);
                Console.WriteLine("AMProductVersion: {0}", queryObj["AMProductVersion"]);
                Console.WriteLine("CleaningActionID: {0}", queryObj["CleaningActionID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("CurrentThreatExecutionStatusID: {0}", queryObj["CurrentThreatExecutionStatusID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("DetectionID: {0}", queryObj["DetectionID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("DetectionSourceTypeID: {0}", queryObj["DetectionSourceTypeID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("DomainUser: {0}", queryObj["DomainUser"]);
                Console.WriteLine("InitialDetectionTime: {0}", queryObj["InitialDetectionTime"]);
                Console.WriteLine("LastThreatStatusChangeTime: {0}", queryObj["LastThreatStatusChangeTime"]);
                Console.WriteLine("ProcessName: {0}", queryObj["ProcessName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("RemediationTime: {0}", queryObj["RemediationTime"]);

                if(queryObj["Resources"] == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Resources: {0}", queryObj["Resources"]);
                else
                {
                    String[] arrResources = (String[])(queryObj["Resources"]);
                    foreach (String arrValue in arrResources)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Resources: {0}", arrValue);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("ThreatID: {0}", queryObj["ThreatID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("ThreatStatusErrorCode: {0}", queryObj["ThreatStatusErrorCode"]);
                Console.WriteLine("ThreatStatusID: {0}", queryObj["ThreatStatusID"]);
            }
```